# Flv file set thumbnail from frame

Tags: flv, thumbnails

I have many videos in .flv and .mp4  formats. I store then in one Windows folder and re-name after downloading so that it becomes easy to find one that I want to play.

It would be best if I can create thumbnail from one of the frames of video file.

Is there a program/utility in which I can open the .flv or .mp4 file, play, pause and take the screen/frame and set it as thumbnail of that file?

I did my best to find it on internet but failed hence thought to reach out to Gurus.

Thanks in advance,
Jay

Answer (score 0):

I think [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) and [mencoder](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html) can do this

Comment: Thanks Jurassic_C

When played FLV in SMplayer , it shows "Player has crashed. See the log for more info".

Downloaded ffmpg, but cannot figure out how to use.

I am okay to buy any shareware tool that can do the job. Any suggestions please?